# React props with map function not working

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-props

Trying to test my functions and get the items from 'names' to be rendered onto the page using props. Looked over tutorials and unsure why its not showing?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
const names =[
    {
        projectname: "Project 1",
        emoji: "happy",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 2",
        emoji: "sad",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 3",
        emoji: "angry",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 4",
        emoji: "confused",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 5",
        emoji: "wink",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 6",
        emoji: "smile",
    }

]

function cards(props){
    <>
    <h1>{props.projectname}</h1>
    <h2>{props.emoji}</h2>
    </>
}

function Projects(){
    return(
        <>
        <div className="projectsAll">
            <h1> This is a test</h1>
            {names.map((cards) => (
                <cards
                projectname={cards.projectname}
                emoji={cards.emoji}
                />
            ))
        }
        </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default Projects
```

This is my app.js file which is correctly showing the 'this is a test'

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Header from './pages/Header';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import About from './pages/AboutMe';
import Projects from './pages/Projects';


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
         <Header /> 
         <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="/aboutme" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
          <Route path="/contactme" element={<Contact />} />
         </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

I want to projectname and emojis to be rendered onto the page,

Answer (score 2):

There were a few errors, first, the `JSX` function should have a name starting with a capital letter so, from `cards` to `Cards`.

This is done so that you can use this function as a `tag` in other functions.

Secondly added the `return` statement to the `Cards` function.

This is the updated `Projects.jsx`,

```
import React from 'react'
const names =[
    {
        projectname: "Project 1",
        emoji: "happy",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 2",
        emoji: "sad",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 3",
        emoji: "angry",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 4",
        emoji: "confused",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 5",
        emoji: "wink",
    },
    {
        projectname: "Project 6",
        emoji: "smile",
    }

]

function Cards(props){
  return(
    <>
    <h1>{props.projectname}</h1>
    <h2>{props.emoji}</h2>
    </>
  )
}

function Projects(){
    return(
        <>
        <div className="projectsAll">
            <h1> This is a test</h1>
            {names.map((cards) => (
                <Cards
                projectname={cards.projectname}
                emoji={cards.emoji}
                />
            ))
        }
        </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default Projects
```